# Unable to use Tmux Config

Tags: linux, configuration, tmux

So I am trying to use and learn tmux. But I want to change some tmux default settings like C-b to C-a.
So I created a .tmux.config file in my ~/ directory. This is in my config file:

```
# Send prefix
set-option -g prefix C-a
unbind-key C-a
bind-key C-a send-prefix

# Use Alt-arrow keys to switch panes
bind -n M-Left select-pane -L
bind -n M-Right select-pane -R
bind -n M-Up select-pane -U
bind -n M-Down select-pane -D

# Shift arrow to switch windows
bind -n S-Left previous-window
bind -n S-Right next-window

# Mouse mode
setw -g mouse on

# Set easier window split keys
bind-key v split-window -h
bind-key h split-window -v

# Easy config reload
bind-key r source-file ~/.tmux.conf \; display-message "~/.tmux.conf reloaded."
```

So I restarted my terminal session but still the binds don't work. It's still set to C-b not C-a

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the it wasn't picking up the config file was because I incorrectly named it **.tmux.config** and the correct name of the file is **.tmux.conf**